# AngularJS $locationProvider.html5Mode not working on localhost

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get rid of the hashtag that appears in my ui-router URLs. (http://localhost:3000/email doesn't work but http://localhost:3000/#email works. After scouring SO, I haven't found a case that works for me. I'm running locally for now, so I assume I don't need any "Server configuration" and I included "" in my index.html.

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])



    .controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.$route = $route;
        $scope.$location = $location;
        $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
    })

    .config([
            ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {

                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/email');

                // PAGES

                $stateProvider

                    .state('email', {
                    url: '/email',
                    templateUrl: '../pages/email.html',
                    controller: 'EmailController'
                })

                .state('about', {
                    url: '/about',
                    templateUrl: '../pages/about.html',
                    controller: 'AboutController'
                })

                // ... the rest...

                $locationProvider
                    .html5Mode(true); // enable html5Mode for pushstate ('#'-less URLs DOESN'T WORK)
                    .hashPrefix('!');

                $provide.decorator('$sniffer', function($delegate) {
                    $delegate.history = false;
                    return $delegate;
                });

            }]);
```

Comment: You need to configure your local server as the documentation recommends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either do this in your run block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

And  your url's will be changed from domain.com/#foo to domain.com/foo (this requires no explicit base).

...or do this in your run block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

...and then add this to your html `<head>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

This solution provides the same outcome as the first, except that now there is a specified base.

Comment: Nothing you guys said is working. I changed the base thing in my head tags, and added what you said  to run block. Is it because I'm using Angular Materialize? https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize

Comment: Unfortunately all your answers were great, but I had to choose one. I simply had to just start over from scratch from a new plunker from a scotch.io tutorial http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7?p=preview and slowly build over that. I literally couldn't trace the problem.

Comment: materialize / jquery don't seem to play nicely with html5mode because certain components rely on #, such as modals and tabs...

Comment: i have tried this in my code but it is not working for me! can you please help me how to configure this

Comment: @SantoshRaju This post was years ago, check the version of Angular you're using and make sure this is still compatible.

Comment: is there any possible solution

Comment: If you are using your local, try adding the full path as your base.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try this code? I think it may be down to one of these reasons.

- Config dependencies weren't set correctly (out of order)
- That .hasPrefix(!) was put in after a semi-colon.
- Also need to assign a base location in your `<head>` tag using `<base href='/'>` (or maybe '/email' ?)

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])

```
.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.$route = $route;
    $scope.$location = $location;
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/email');

    // PAGES

    $stateProvider

        .state('email', {
            url: '/email',
            templateUrl: '../pages/email.html',
            controller: 'EmailController'
        })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: '../pages/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $provide.decorator('$sniffer', function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.history = false;
        return $delegate;
    });
```

});

Apologies, I can't get the code sample to behave.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set base in HTML-file same as follow:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
</html>
```

and you should remove  `.hashPrefix('!');` at config, so this code will same here:

```
$stateProvider

    .state('email', {
    url: '/email',
    templateUrl: '../pages/email.html',
    controller: 'EmailController'
})

.state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: '../pages/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutController'
})

// ... the rest...

$locationProvider
    .html5Mode(true); // enable html5Mode for pushstate ('#'-less URLs DOESN'T WORK)

$provide.decorator('$sniffer', function($delegate) {
    $delegate.history = false;
    return $delegate;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app config will look like this

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) { 
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: 'url',
        controller : 'mainController'
    })
});
```

Use  tag in your page head

```
<base  href="abc.com/"/>
```

This may create problem with following href, will not load the page properly

```
<a href="abc.com/about">About Us</a>
```

To overcome this use `target="_self"` in anchor tag as follow

```
<a href="abc.com/about" target="_self">About Us</a>
```